# Static friction greater than kinetic friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

Please explain why static friction is greater than kinetic friction logically.
Speak about it microscopically and tell what does happen on surfaces of objects by considering electromagnetic force between atoms on surface.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are there both Static and Kinetic Friction?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16633/)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/541/2451 and links therein.